# What is the difference between django.conf.settings and global_settings?

Tags: python, django

What is the difference between `django.conf.settings` and `django.conf.global_settings` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`settings` is a proxy object that you use in your code to access the settings.

`global_settings` is a module internal to Django, containing default settings, used when you leave out a variable out of project's settings. I.e. you don't touch it, unless you're changing Django core.

Comment: You forgot this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/ and https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/conf/global_settings.py

Comment: Reason I asked is that some example settings file will do this `from django.conf.global_settings import *`.

Comment: @BonAmi: It's more than likely unnecessary.